# Cryptographically Secure Elliptic Curve

Tags: elliptic-curves, discrete-logarithm, elliptic-curve-generation, pohlig-hellman, pollard-rho

What are the properties a cryptographically secure Elliptic Curve must have?
I have started to create a list and wanted to know if I forgot some important points, and if it is correct so far:

A curve $E$ over a finite field $\mathbb{F}_q$ with $\#E(\mathbb{F}_q)=h\cdot p$ is considered to be cryptographically secure if:

- rigidity, as mentioned before the generation of the curve should be documented or random
- $p>2^{200}$ so that the ECDLP is hard.
- $p\not|(q^k -1)$, for $k<30$ to exclude the possibility of transfers (such as MOV or Frey-Rück)
- $p\not=q$, as well to avoid MOV and Frey-Rück and the Anomalous curve Attack
- $q$ should be a large prime
- the cofactor $h$ should be very small to avoid the Pohlig-Hellman attack
- $p$ should be a large prime so that the Pollard-Rho algorithm is inefficient
- twist security, check that the twists of the elliptic curve are cryptographically secure as well
- little plus: prime in efficient form (such as Merzenne-primes)
- Complete addition- and multiplication- formulas to avoid side-channel attacks

Comment: Did you go over all the properties listed at Daniel's and Tanja's [safe curves](https://safecurves.cr.yp.to/) site?

Comment: I think I have them all. I did not include the CM field discriminant condition, since there is no reason, up-to-date, to say that a curve with a small CM field discriminant is less secure. But I wanted to be 100% sure that I got all important properties for a cryptographically secure curve. So I would be happy if someone could check my list !

Comment: No need to follow my advice, but you could make your list a public wiki answer instead of putting it in the question. It will be hard to know for sure if any other items delivered by anyone will be complete. Except maybe if it is Poncho :)

Comment: I think a $p$ of 160 bits is too small according to today's standards. Global bitcoin mining does something like $2^{90}$ hashes per year, so $2^{80}$ operations to break your ECDLP is feasible or almost feasible (although certainly not cheap). Most people seem to agree that a 256-bit group is sufficient for the foreseeable future (disregarding the potential existence of big quantum computers).

Comment: Thank you for the remark. In SafeCurves they require $2^{200}$ ''SafeCurves requires ℓ to be at least 2^200. ''. I got the $2^{160}$ from ''Evaluation Report for Cryptrec: Security Level of Cryptography – Ecdlp Mathematical Problem'' from 2002, but its good to know that this is out-dated!

Comment: NIST starts at 192 bits for prime curves, the curves before that have been removed from the FIPS 186-4 standard. The FIPS table at https://keylength.com/ however mentions a 224 bit curve for security in the period 2016-2030 or a 256 bity key for longer term security (again, for curves over a prime field).